# What signs in Gemmorah suggest that a ruling must hold forever?

Tags: talmud-gemara, halacha-theory

The reasoning of the Gemmorah's Rabbis is very fluid and everchanging, each generation offering new interpretations, considerations, measures, and decrees.

Usually, the development of the Halachah, following the Gemmarah, takes two paths: attributing the Halachah to particular circumstances of their times and adapting it to the current or accepting its universality. This pattern is very common, for example, with laws of idolatry, most of which are irrelevant today and some were allowed and some hold still.

Besides some common logic, are there any signs in the text of the Gemmorah (and other Rabbinical literature) that indicate that a certain Halachah/ruling/decree is relative to their times and conditions, but another should not change, no matter what changes in human knowledge or nature will occur?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The 5th chapter of Maaser Sheini has both, immediately adjacent to each other.

[Maaser Sheini 5:10-14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Maaser_Sheni.5.10-14) gives laws of viduy maaser, and then [Mishnah 15](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Maaser_Sheni.5.15) says that at a particular time Yochanan Kohen Gadol said not to do it.  Since 10-14 weren't practically applicable at the time of the mishnah, the implication is that they're universal whenever viduy maaser applies.  On the other hand, Yochanan Kohen Gadol's decree to stop it was temporary (and couldn't be otherwise - it's an explicit mitzvah in the Torah).

Comment: I +1 for your effort, but couldn't grasp the logic. How do you infer "Since... the implication is"? Because Mishnah lists it? Mishnah lists a lot of nonpractical and non-Halachic issues and approaches. Is there something in the TEXT of the Mishnah that indicates that Yochanan's decree was temporary?